# Can't play mp4 video in Safari served by nodejs server

Tags: node.js, html, html5-video

I'm having a problem loading mp4 video files on Safari being served from my nodejs server. The problem does not exist on Chrome.

To illustrate the problem, I have a simple html webpage which reads an mp4 file `mov_bbb.mp4` served from w3schools. I then download the same file and serve it from my nodejs server.

`vid1` (served from w3schools) loads fine on both Chrome and Safari.

`vid2` (served from my nodejs server) load fine on Chrome but not on Safari.

Here's a screenshot of what I see in Chrome:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of what I see in Safari:

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="vid1" controls preload="auto" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    <video id="vid2" controls preload="auto" src="http://localhost:8125/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my nodejs server:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('request starting...');

    var filePath = '.' + request.url;
    if (filePath == './')
        filePath = './index.html';

    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType = 'video/mp4';

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            if(error.code == 'ENOENT'){
                fs.readFile('./404.html', function(error, content) {
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                    response.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            }
            else {
                response.writeHead(500);
                response.end('Sorry, check with the site admin for error: '+error.code+' ..\n');
                response.end();
            }
        }
        else {
            response.writeHead(200, {
            });
            response.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });

}).listen(8125);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8125/');
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**Update:**

Revised nodejs code. Still same issue on Safari though:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  console.log('request starting...');

  var filePath = '.' + request.url;
  if (filePath == './') {
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    filePath = './index.html';
  } else {
    var contentType = 'video/mp4';
  }

  var rstream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
  rstream.on('error', function(error) {
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
  });
  rstream.on('open', function () {
    response.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': contentType,
    });
  });
  rstream.pipe(response);
}).listen(8125);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8125/');
```

Also chrome inspector for http headers:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the video playback has to do with handling the `Content-Range` range header which must be implemented on the server. Chrome and Safari send different request headers. In my case Chrome sends a single request with range:

```
bytes=0-
```

Whereas Safari sends multiple requests:

```
bytes=0-1
bytes=0-1013150
bytes=197534-1013150
```

For more information see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360060/video-streaming-with-html-5-via-node-js/29126190) and for specific code that worked for me see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29126190/2138200).

Comment: @stthoms...I am facing same issue ...not working on safari...Did u find the fix...If so can u share it..

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't use `readFile()` for serving files, it causes unnecessary (potentially high) memory usage because it's loading the entire file into memory. Use `fs.createReadStream()` and pipe it to the `response` instead.

Secondly and most importantly, a `Content-Type` is not being sent in the success case. Also, the `Content-Type` is wrong in the error case because text/html data is being sent in the response, not video/mp4 data.

Additionally, arbitrary paths should not be passed to filesystem calls because someone could pass a malicious path (including relative paths to get to the filesystem root) and read sensitive information from your filesystem (e.g. private keys, passwords, etc.).

Lastly, if you're going to write a `Buffer` to a response, you don't need to specify an encoding (e.g. `'utf-8'`) because the data is already in `Buffer` form.

Comment: Upvoting for nodejs suggestions although the issue remains.