# do streams block the thread in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm working on a project where I need to create a video streaming server using Nodejs, and I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360060/video-streaming-with-html-5-via-node-js)
that it is possible to do that, But now the question arises that if I create a new read stream using `fs.createReadStream(path, {start: start, end: end});` then would it block a worker thread until the stream is closed? Because according to the Node's documentation it states that the `fs` module utilises `worker threads`, and we should avoid blocking the event loop as well as the worker threads. To summarize my question I would like to know do `streams` block a thread until they are closed? or is the thread only used when we access the buffer to read a chunk of data from that stream? Also is it a bad idea to create a video streaming server using Nodejs? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Where is the "fs" uses "worker threads" documented? You will most likely not get an usefull answer if anything is a "bad idea" on SO.

Comment: didn't do it myself, but video streaming is good and easy idea with node. take a look here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976123/streaming-a-video-file-to-an-html5-video-player-with-node-js-so-that-the-video-c